# How do I determine virtual user amount and pacing if the client cannot give me any real data about the website?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I've come across many clients who aren't really able to provide real production data about a website's peak usage. I often do not get peak pageviews per hour, etc.

In these circumstances, besides just guessing or going with what "feels right" (i.e. making it all up), how exactly does one come up with a realistic workload model with an appropriate # of virtual users and a good pacing value?

I use Loadrunner for my performance/load testing.

Comment: maybe a goal oriented scenario is suitable instead of # of vusers, just set transaction/hits per second, if you can "guess" out the concurrent user numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask for the logs for a month.

- Find the stats for session duration, then count the number of distinct IP's blocked by session duration.
- Once you have the high volume hour, count the number of page instances.  Business processes will typically have a termination page which is distinct and allows you to understand how many times a particular action takes place, such as request new password, update profile, business process 1, etc...

With this you will have a measurement of users and actions.  You will want your stakeholder to take ownership of this data.  As Quality assurance, we should not own both the requirement and the test against it. We should own one, but not both. If your client will not own the requirement, cascading it down to rest of the organization, assume you will be left out in the cold with a result they do not like....i.e., defects that need to be addressed before deployment to production.

Now comes your largest challenge, which is something that needs to be fixed with a process issue by your client.....You are about to test using requirements that no other part of the organization, architecture, development, platform engineering, had when they built the solution.   Even if your requirements are a perfect recovery, plus some amount for growth, any defects you find will be challenged aggressively.

Your test will not match any assumptions or requirements used by any other portion of the organization.

And, in a sense, these other orgs will be correct in aggressively challenging your results.  It really isn't fair to hold their designed solution to a set of requirements which were not in place when they made decisions which impacted scalability and response times for the system.   You would be wise to call this out with your clients before the first execution of any performance test.

You can buy yourself some time.  If the client does have a demand for a particular response time, such as an adoption of the Google [RAIL](https://web.dev/rail/) model, then you can implement a gate before accepting any code for multi-user performance testing that the code SHALL BE compliant for a single user.  It is not going to get any faster for two or more users.  Implementing this hard gate will solve about 80% of your performance issues, for the changes required to bring code into compliance for a single user most often will have benefits on the multi-user front.

You can buy yourself some time in a second way as well.  Take a look at their current site using tools such as Google [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse) and [GTMetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/).  Most of us are creatures of habit, that includes architect, developers, and ops personnel.  We design, build, deploy to patterns we know and are comfortable with....usually the same ones over and over again until we are forced to make a change.  It is highly likely that the performance antipatterns pulled from Lighthouse and GTMetrix will be carried forward into a future release unless they are called out for mitigation. Begin citing defects directly off of these tools before you even run a performance test.   You will need management support, but you might consider not even accepting a build for multi-user performance testing until GTMetrix scores at least a B across the board and Lighthouse a score of 90 or better.

This should leave edge cases when you do get to multi-user performance testing, such as too early allocation of a resource, holding onto resources too long, too large of a resource allocation, hitting something too often, lock contention on a shared resource.  An architectural review might pick up on these, where someone might say, "we are pre-allocating this because.....," or "Marketing says we need to hold the cart for 30 minutes before de-allocation," or "...."   Well, you get the idea.

Don't forget to have the database profiler running while functional testing is going on.  You are likely to pick up a few missing indexes or high cost queries here which should be addressed before multi-user performance testing as well.

You are probably wondering why am I pointing out all of these things before your performance test takes place.  Darnit, you are hired to engage in a performance test!  The test you are about to conduct is very high risk politically.  Even if it finds something ugly, because the other parts of the organization did not benefit from the requirements, the result is likely to be rejected until the issue shows up in production.  By shifting the focus to objective measures even before you need to run two users in anger together there are many avenues to finding and fixing performance issues which are far less politically volatile.  Food for thought.

Comment: This is a wonderfully comprehensive answer. Thank you, James.

Comment: James, once you have the "measurement of users and actions", is there a formula you use to determine pacing and/or load to apply, etc. If so, what is it?

Comment: To determine users, first I collect session duration.  Using a log processing tool I collect the time between the first request and the last request from a given IP/Session, blocked by hour.   Now that I have session duration, I do a count of unique IP's/sessions blocked/quantized by session duration.  Then, unique end pages.  I know users.  I know transaction volume.  It becomes easy to set up a pacing model